# How to connect to Oracle11g client VS2010 windows8 os 64bit

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, windows-8, oracle11g

I am using vs2010 to create a web app that takes data from a database and creates charts using this data. My only problem is I cant connect to the database. I've searched everywhere for the past week. My os is windows8 64bit. I'M trying to connect to an oracle 11g client. Please help. I'm programming in c#. (ODAC not working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after searching for more than a week, I finally decided to go to the oracle site and there I looked through  a few discussions I found out that oracle is supported from 11.2 release upwards on vs2010 windows 8